# mod_ssl wont get installed

Tags: apache-httpd, ssl

Hi,

I am trying to install mod_os on apache with this:

```
yum install mod_ssl
```

I get no error whatsoever. It only says

```
Transaction Summary
================================================================================
Install  1 Package

Total download size: 112 k
Installed size: 224 k
Is this ok [y/d/N]: Exiting on user command
Your transaction was saved, rerun it with:
 yum load-transaction /tmp/yum_save_tx.2020-04-25.04-38.ctOM7v.yumtx
```

that means its installed, right? However, when I run rpm -V mod_ssl it says its not installed. Why is that?

Thank you.

Comment: No. 'transaction saved' means it was **NOT executed**, because you didn't answer y, you (somehow) accepted the default answer of n (the prompt y/d/N means the default is n).

Answer (score 0):

Okay, make sure to use -y like this

```
yum install mod_ssl
```